# Git user permissions

Tags: git, permissions, ssh, repository

I have a local repo and remote --bare repository set.

Each of my hosting packages has its own user and group (with no ssh access), so I have so permissions problems.

I have worked around this by setting up my remote repo as ssh://root@... and createing post-receive hook to apply `chown correctuser:correctgroup -R public_html/`

This is as you can see not ideal as I involve 'root' and that should not be the case.

Would '`git init --bare --shared`' help at all?

I would like to be able to push remotely as root and adding 'git' to all of my groups (packages) didn't help either.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep `root` and its `chown` for your ssh access, but limiting the ssh session to only git commands, with an **[authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html)** like **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**.

`--shared` option ([man `git init`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html))isn't exactly suited when you have multiple groups:

```
--shared[=(false|true|umask|group|all|world|everybody|0xxx)]
```

> Specify that the git repository is to be shared amongst several users.
>   This **allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository**.
>   When specified, the config variable "`core.sharedRepository`" is set so that files and directories under `$GIT_DIR` are created with the requested permissions.
>   When not specified, git will use permissions reported by umask(2).

Comment: Hmm, this would not quite work as I don't want to 'limit' root privileges. And I am the only ssh user on this server so gitolite seem a bit over doing it. ;(

Comment: @user1113177 it would work of you generate a public/private key dedicated for those git commands, while keeping the default ones for root interactive shell session. You can use several public/private keys for ssh, as illustrated for instance in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998273/w-access-for-gitolite-admin-denied-to-user/12998492#12998492

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://serverfault.com/questions/133508/how-to-prevent-ssh-git-push-to-set-file-ownership

Basically you set the SUID and SGID bits.