# W access for gitolite-admin DENIED to user

Tags: git, msysgit, gitolite

I've been trying very hard to get gitolite working.  I used the package approach and am able to do a first "git push" with a first user to the server.  After that, if if I add a key and try to push something again, I get an error saying "W access for gitolite-admin DENIED to mike"- note that it's supposed to be using the gitolite user- not my username.  I guess this is because I'm adding private keys for both users in my .bash_profile.  (I'm using msysgit)...

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess this is because I'm adding private keys for both users

True, you should use a dedicated public/private key for the `gitolite` user, the one which is also used for ssh access.
You can confirm it by looking in the gitolite logs (in `~gitolite/.gitolite/logs`)

Using multiple keys is done through a `config` file.
See as an example "[users are asked for password while using gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906633/users-are-asked-for-password-while-using-gitolite/10909791#10909791)".
The `%HOME%/.ssh/config` file could contain something like:

```
HostName gitoliteserver 
    User gitolite
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite

Host mikegitolite
    HostName gitoliteserver 
    User mike 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Don't forget to define `HOME` is you are on Windows: it isn't defined by default)

---

The [OP Mike Gagnon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763113/mike-gagnon) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998273/w-access-for-gitolite-admin-denied-to-user/12998492#comment17661203_12998492) the following config is working:

```
host gitolite 
user gitolite 
hostname myhost 
port 443 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite

host edison 
user gitolite 
hostname myhost 
port 443 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mike
```

Comment: Thanks - it works and my config looks like this:

host gitolite
 user gitolite
 hostname myhost
 port 443
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite

host edison
 user gitolite
 hostname myhost
 port 443
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mike

Comment: @MikeGagnon Excellent. I have included your config file in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in that I could only make one push to a new gitolite repo, then I lost access.
I was able to fix this by adding my username to the .conf file on the first push:

> %> cat conf/gitolite.conf repo    gitolite-admin
>           RW+     =   git-admin **myusername**